# Android application crash using Firebase Realtime Database in Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an Android app connected to Firebase and I'm using Realtime Database in it.

The problem is that the app, that I've installed on the emulator keeps crashing after user logs in.

I think it's a problem related to the fact that somehow the app is unable to retrieve user's data from the database. I've checked Firebase Documentation but nothing helped me. All my Gradle files are set up and sync correctly. I'm really stuck and don't know what to do.

Please help me I would be really grateful.

**PS This is what is shown by Android Studio in the RUN SECTION when the app crashes**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.e.youdemo, PID: 26450
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.e.youdemo.UserProfile
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:530)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:312)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:413)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:212)
        at com.e.youdemo.Menu$1.onDataChange(Menu.java:91)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**EDIT**

This is the method wich starts at line 91 of "Menu Activity" reported in the log

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue (UserProfile.class);
    CurrentUserName.setText (Objects.requireNonNull (userProfile).getName ());
    CurrentUserAge.setText (MessageFormat.format ("{0} anni", userProfile.getAge ()));
    CurrentUserGender.setText (userProfile.getGender ());
    CurrentUserWeight.setText (MessageFormat.format ("{0} kg", userProfile.getWeight ()));
    CurrentUserHeight.setText (MessageFormat.format ("{0} cm", userProfile.getHeight ()));
}
```

**EDIT**

```
package com.e.youdemo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
    private String Name;
    private String Age;
    private String Gender;
    private String Weight;
    private String Height;

    public UserProfile () {}

    UserProfile(String Name, String Age, String Gender, String Weight, String Height) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Weight = Weight;
        this.Height = Height;
    }

    String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    String getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }

    String getWeight() {
        return Weight;
    }

    String getHeight() {
        return Height;
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    void setAge(String age) {
        Age = age;
    }

    void setGender(String gender) {
        Gender = gender;
    }

    void setWeight(String weight) {
        Weight = weight;
    }

    void setHeight(String height) {
        Height = height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order for people to be able to help you, you do need to share your code. Please edit your question and maybe have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please add the content of yout `UserProfile`. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: In the next EDIT there is the whole code of the UserProfile class, thank you @AlexMamo

Comment: Please add FirebaseDatabase userProfile node data

Comment: Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: In the next EDIT there is all my JSON file of my database. @AlexMamo

Comment: The  related node in my database is  "User Info" **
     age,
     gender,
     height,
     name,
     weight   **      (CHILDREN)      @SilverskyTechnology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
    private String Name;
    private String Age;
    private String Gender;
    private String Weight;
    private String Height;
}
```

with

```
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String gender;
    private String weight;
    private String height;
}
```

Comment: Sorry does not work

Comment: Please provide data you get in `dataSnapshot` in `public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)`

Comment: Firebase requires public getter/setter methods

Comment: Thanks now it works just fine!!